# Prevent FTP users from moving directories

Tags: centos, permissions, users, ftp, mv

I'm essentially trying to disable the `mv` command for FTP users on my CentOS server.

I was thinking of editing their `.bash_profile` file and using this:

```
alias mv=""
```

But that feels system breaking. Feels like there may be an actual, secure and better way to disable mv for FTP users.

All I want to allow for FTP users is `PUT`, `GET` and `DELETE`.

How do I restrict `mv` for FTP users properly?

Comment: What ftp server software are you using?

Comment: @JeffSchaller er not sure actually - it's just out-the-box CentOS

Comment: Are the users the only ones using the FTP server? Have you tried adding cmds_allowed=STOR,RETR,DELE to your etc/vsftpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

## Non-ftp way

### Using file-system permissions.

You could make it so that directories and file are not in the same directories. Then you can remove write permission of the parent directories.

#### Explanation

In Unix, a file can not be added, removed, or renamed, if it is in a directory where the user does not have write permission. Therefore to prevent a file/directory from being moved, put it in a directory where there are no write permissions. Note the owner of the directory, can change the permissions.

You may need to re-arrange the directory structure, to do this.

### Use the sticky-bit.

You can not remove a file (directory or anything else) from a directory with the sticky-bit set, unless you are the owner. This will also stop users removing/renaming files, unless they own them.

Comment: I feel a little lost with that haha sorry, could you explain a little further please? :)

Comment: ah I'm with ya! Ok ... only problem is, it's a Magento 1 website, so I don't have any flexibility in changing dir structure without possibly killing Magento 1